# Leviticus 11:26 Divided Hoof vs Cloven Footed

Tags: kashrut-kosher, torah-study, animals, non-kosher-species

> [Leviticus 11:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.11.26?lang=bi&aliyot=0)
>
> even every living thing which divides the hoof, and is not cloven
> footed, and does not bring up the cud, they are unclean to you; anyone
> who touches them shall be unclean.

What's the difference between "divided hoof" and "cloven footed"? Can you give me examples of animals that has "divided hoof & wholly cloven footed" and "divided hoof & is not cloven footed".
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Leviticus.11.26.1?lang=bi) explains the verse to be referring to animals with partially, but not fully, split 'hooves':

> WHICH DIVIDETH THE HOOF AND IS NOT CLOVEN FOOTED, such as the camel, the hoof of which is split on top but is attached below

So, according to Rashi, cows, sheep, goats, deer, gazelles etc. have fully cloven hooves, whereas camels have 'hooves' which are divided, but not [fully] cloven.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative translation, probably clearer is

> With regard to any animal that has hooves but they are not split or
> does not bring up the cud, it is impure to you.

A horse is an example of such an animal: it has hooves that are not split and it is not kosher.

A cow is an example of an animal with hooves which are split and which is kosher.

Source: Chumash Steinsaltz